# Diophantine system of equations

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to know if there is an efficient way to find the smallest (*i.e* lexicographically) triplet $(a,b,c)$ of **integers** verifying $$a^2+b^2+c^2 = x$$ $$a^3+b^3+c^3=y$$ $$a^4+b^4 + c^4 = z$$ if $(x,y,z)$ is known.

We assume that a solution exists for that triplet $(x,y,z)$.

Originally, this question is part of an algorithmic problem. So what I want is a fast way to find the triplet without having to brute-force.

What I've tried (the brute-force approach): going through all the possible values of $a$ since we can deduce an upper bound for its value, we remain with three equations where it's easy to find $b$ and $c$ and see if they are integers.

**EDIT:** We may assume as well that $a<b<c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b,c$ are integers such that

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = x$$
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = y$$
$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = z$$

then the following divisibility conditions must hold:

$$
\left(
a + b + c
\right)
\mid 
\left(
x^2 - 2z
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
4\left(ab + bc + ca\right)
\right) 
\mid 
\left(
x^4 + 6x^2z - 16xy^2 + 9z^2
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
2abc
\right)^2 
\mid 
\left(
x^6 - 4x^3y^2 - 3x^2z^2 + 12xy^2z - 4y^4 - 2z^3
\right)
$$

Of these, the last will cut down your search considerably.

Comment: Can you please provide a quick hint how did you get these divisibility conditions ?

Comment: @Guru: I used Maple's Groebner basis package to "solve" for the elementary symmetric functions of $a,b,c$ in terms of $x,y,z$

Comment: Besides, these conditions do not solve the problem since with the condition $a<b<c$ we get $4a^6 < RHS$ but RHS can be very big, the range of searching for a is still large. Algorithmically, I start searching a beginning from 0, and whenever I get a solution for $a$ I stop the loop. Therefore, reducing the upper bound does not make any change. Finding a lower bound or a lower bound for $a$ would be more helpful.

Comment: For given integers $x,y,z$, Just _factor_ the RHS (integer factors).

Comment: Doesn't look like a simple task ..

Comment: Agreed, for the last condition, the RHS might be huge.

But for the first condition, the RHS should be a lot smaller.

Comment: Not enough, ans as I said, the upper bound does not matter, since in anyway I'm going throught all the first values starting from 0, when I find a possible answer I stop. So finding the upper bound doesn't solve the problem. I need a more efficient method.

Comment: Can you give a sample of values of x,y,z for which your current method is too slow?

Comment: Just take large values of a,b,c ( for example 10000, 11000, 12000 ) the resulting triplet (x,y,z) is considered large for my current method. ( Note that the algorithm is supposed to solve many queries of this type, up to 1000)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51008/discussion-between-quasi-and-guru).

Answer (score 0):

If you have software to find real roots, the following result provides another way to find qualifying triples $a,b,c$ ...

Proposition: If $a,b,c$ satisfy $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = x$, $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = y$, $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = z$, then $a,b,c$ are roots of the following 12'th degree polynomial:

$$
p(t) = \left(12\right)\left(t^{12}\right)
-\left(24x\right)\left(t^{10}\right)
-\left(16y\right)\left(t^9\right)
+\left(24x^2-12z\right)\left(t^8\right)
+\left(48xy\right)\left(t^7\right)
$$
$$
-\left(24x^3+8y^2\right)\left(t^6\right)
-\left(24x^2y-24yz\right)\left(t^5\right)
$$
$$
+\left(15x^4+6x^2z-24xy^2+3z^2\right)\left(t^4\right)
+\left(8x^3y-24xyz+16y^3\right)\left(t^3\right)
$$
$$
-\left(6x^5-12x^2y^2-6xz^2+12y^2z\right)\left(t^2\right)
+\left(x^6-4x^3y^2-3x^2z^2+12xy^2z-4y^4-2z^3\right)
$$

Comment: I'm meant to solve just an algorithmic problem ... I mean just submitting some lines of code, so no, I don't think I'll be able to find the roots

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to first get the degree $4$ polynomial of which $a+b+c$ is a root ?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well -- didn't post it.

Apparently it's a live programming contest problem.

I wasn't aware of that when I posted my repsonses.